# cordova, Phonegap push plugin and c# for single registration?

Tags: c#, push-notification, cordova-plugins, registration

is it possible to send a notification to a specific registration(device) using c# server side code to a cordova mobile application having the Phonegap push plugin?

Comment: you have to interact to notification push service of the main OS... GCM for example

Comment: can you please elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is Yes:

But you don't send push notifications directly to devices, you have to go through the platform holders servers. For Android that GCM (google cloud messaging) and for IOS that's APNS (apple push notification server).

To interact with them you could use a library like PushSharp (free) or Amazon web services has a fairly cheep implementation called SNS (simple notification service). Amazon SNS has a .Net api that you can use on the server side.

[Push Sharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp)